# Python ImportError: No module named serial

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port, pip, pyserial

I have installed Python 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 12.4 on a DELL LATITUDE E4300 64 bit and ran:

```
sudo pip install pyserial
```

nevertheless when running:

```
sudo python main.py
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mySerial import *
  File "/home/oscar/ath10k/tools/sanity_test/src/mySerial.py", line 6, in <module>
    import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
```

I looked on other posts but none of them helped me to solve this problem. I don't know what else to do I also ran:

```
sudo -H pip install pyserial
```

and

```
sudo pip install pyserial --upgrade
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Oscar.

Comment: run `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` to print you python path

Answer (score 5):

On my ubuntu 14.4 with python 2.7 as default, I installed pyserial for python3 (which my IDE is using actually) with the help of following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script name is exactly like module name, change mySerial.py to something else.

Comment: In my case work: import serial or from serial import *

Comment: It runs well on other computer with the same file names.

Comment: I changed as you say but I have the same exact error

Comment: In console try: dpkg -l | grep pyserial

results:
ii  python-serial                                               2.6-1build1                                         all          pyserial - module encapsulating access for the serial port

Comment: I tried: dpkg -l | grep pyserial

Resulted in: 

ii  python-serial                               2.5-2.1build1                                pyserial - module encapsulating access for the serial port

But still having the same error.

Comment: Can You paste first 6 lines your code - where there is an error?

Comment: All are comments and the line 6 is:
"import serial" which is actually the first line of code

Comment: Try hash: #from mySerial import * and use only import serial

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing pyserial from source code instead than doing it with pip.

I do not know why it works this way and when using pip it prints error messages.