# import serial - Linux Mint 17, 64-bit, python3.5

Tags: import, python-3.5, pyserial

I am going to be asking a question that seems to have been asked numerous times.  However, all of the solutions posted in the others, seems to not be working.  This leads me to believe that my problem may be system related, but I'm not an expert.

I am a newbie to Python, but not to Linux, and not a newbie to software by any means.

I am running Linux Mint, 17.3 (Rosa), 64-bit, and have recently installed Python3.5 per https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3nbfdx/how_to_upgrade_from_python_27_to_35_linux_mint/ and that seems to have worked.

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Nov 19 2016, 10:27:39) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When running:
    pip list | grep pyserial
I get the following:
    pyserial (2.6)

**My problem is simply this**: I can't run the following pyPractice.py file:

```
import serial
```

...with the following cli prompt:

```
me@machine /home/me/Desktop/practice $ python3.5 pyPractice.py
```

I have tried many solutions, such as those posted in the following locations, but all seem to have failed for one reason or another:

1) [pyserial, ImportError: No module named serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086281/pyserial-importerror-no-module-named-serial)

RESULT-> pyserial is already installed, as you can see above.  When I tried to install 'serial', no dice, not recognized

```
me@machine /home/me/Desktop/practice $ sudo pip install serial
[sudo] password for me:
Downloading/unpacking serial
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirements serial
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for serial
Storing debug log for failure in /home/me/.pip/pip.log
```

2) [Python ImportError: No module named serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012189/python-importerror-no-module-named-serial)

RESULT-> nearly the same as above.  Near the end, the proposed fix is to type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

However, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-serial is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  php5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 379 not upgraded.
```

3) [Serial import python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728535/serial-import-python)

RESULT-> No sure...I started to look at this option, but wouldn't you know it, there isn't a serial in my python3.5 packages.  So, even if I did have a path correct, I wouldn't know where to start.

---

I am pretty new to Python, so feel free to take me back to basics.  I am not adverse to reading, so links to sites which explain your thoughts are acceptable.  I am pretty handy with Linux.

[somewhat useless side note: I am trying to start out slow, but am trying to work through running a simple cube drawing script, which was found [here](http://openglsamples.sourceforge.net/cube_py.html) ]

Answer (score 0):

In your first method there are two errors: for Python 3 you should use the command `pip3`, and the module is called `pyserial`.
As for the second method, maybe the package has been installed improperly. Try to remove it and install again, maybe with the option `--reinstall`. Also maybe the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3-serial` would help.